# Isotope JS tabs shows all contents on first loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have used Isotope JS to show the contents within the vertical tabs. However, each tabs have different contents, **when the initial time of loading it shows contents from all tabs for a little bit of time.** After 1-2 sec it will be fine. Can we solve that loading time issue? Actually, on loading time I need to show only contents from the first tab.

```js
var first = $(".item:first")
$('#items').isotope({
  filter: first
});
// Filters out items
$('#filters a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('#items').isotope({
    filter: selector
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.isotop-tabs {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.isotop-tabs li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.isotop-tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.4/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div id="isotope">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="isotop-tabs" id="filters">
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".one">Item one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".two">Item two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".three">Item three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".four">Item four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".five">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div id="items" class="item-list">
      <div class="item one">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item two">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Two</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item three">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Three</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item four">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Four</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item five">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Five</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/c0kf8nyf/3/

Comment: You can keep - <div id="items" class="item-list"  style="display: none;"> Hide all initially and then on document on load function where you are initializing first one show this div like this - var first = $(".item:first");
$('#items').show();
$('#items').isotope({
  filter: first
});

Comment: @T.Shah Thanks for the support..! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do **something like**:

```js
$('#items').isotope({
  // Options
}).addClass('is-show');
```

and **CSS**:

```css
#items {
  display:none;
}
#items.is-show {
  display: block;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/b7Lw18ny/